# Runing mysql in Docker with persisting data to my created dicrectory

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run mysql in Docker with persisting data to my created dicrectory.

```
docker run --name mysql-mac -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_strong_password -d mysql:latest -v /Users/alexeyzhulin/Projects/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Container started and stopped.
In container logs I could see:

```
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17 16:53:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17 16:53:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17 16:53:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17 16:53:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17T16:53:45.915750Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17T16:53:45.915794Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010083] [Server] --verbose is for use with --help; did you mean --log-error-verbosity?
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17T16:53:45.915904Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) initializing of server in progress as process 80
2023-07-17 21:53:45 2023-07-17T16:53:45.921828Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-17 21:53:46 2023-07-17T16:53:46.234691Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-07-17 21:53:46 2023-07-17T16:53:46.768297Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010147] [Server] Too many arguments (first extra is '/Users/alexeyzhulin/Projects/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql').
2023-07-17 21:53:46 2023-07-17T16:53:46.768321Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-07-17 21:53:46 2023-07-17T16:53:46.768325Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-17 21:53:48 2023-07-17T16:53:48.204456Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

When I run container without persisting data to my created dicrectory it works fine.

```
docker run --name mysql-mac -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_strong_password -d mysql:latest
```

How to run mysql in Docker with persisting data to my created dicrectory?

Comment: The `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path` option needs to be _before_ the `mysql:latest` image name.  Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run as the main container process.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your created directory already owned by mysql user

Comment: I've changed permission for data dir to ```chmod 777 mysql``` but result the same